# how to use java substring on Japanese utf-8 kanji

Tags: java, string, utf-8, substring

Is it possible to use substring to extract single utf8 kanji from a string?  The problem is that utf-8 "characters" can have a length of 1, 2 or 3.

For instance, length of "" is 6 so String.substring(1, 2) doesn't get the first complete character.

In PERL, I could just use substr("", 1, 1) to get the first character, or substr("", 2, 1) to get the second character.

UPDATE:
Based on @msandiford's suggestion, I came up with this.

```
public class SplitKanji {
    private String [] splitKanji;
    private SplitKanji(String string) {
        int cpCount = string.codePointCount(0, string.length());
        splitKanji = new String[cpCount];
        int nextSlot = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length();) {
            int ii = string.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1);
            splitKanji[nextSlot++] = string.substring(i, ii);
            i = ii;
        }
    }
    private String[] get() {
        return splitKanji;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String startKanji = "私今日";
        SplitKanji myStuff = new SplitKanji(startKanji);
        String [] split = myStuff.get();
        System.out.print(startKanji + "=");
        for(String kanji: split)
            System.out.print(kanji + ":" + kanji.length() + ", ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd convert UTF-8 byte stream into a proper Unicode string, did the substring operation, and encoded the result back into UTF-8. Specify your programming language; there are libraries capable of this on raw UTF-8 streams, too, if you must.

Comment: Actually, a codepoint takes 1 UTF-32 codeunit, up to 2 UTF-16 codeunits or up to 4 UTF-8 codeunits. Most of the time, operating at the codeunit level is sufficient, but it seems you are interested in codepoints or even graphemes (which consist of 1 to infinite codepoints). As PERL strings are UTF-32, you can use substr there, while it won't work in Java.

Comment: Actually, I just want to parse a large UTF-8 file without converting to String[] using split.  String allocation seems to be an expensive operation.  Also -- I use 'use utf-8' in most of my PERL.  If it's using utf-32, it's transparent at the programming level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract individual Unicode codepoints from the `String` like so:

```
  public static final String KANJI = "";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(KANJI.length());                         // 6
    System.out.println(KANJI.codePointCount(0, KANJI.length()));// 3

    // Loop over each code point
    for (int i = 0; i < KANJI.length(); )
    {
      System.out.println(KANJI.codePointAt(i));
      i = KANJI.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1);
    }

    // Extract the third codepoint
    int indexForThirdCodePoint = KANJI.offsetByCodePoints(0, 2);
    int thirdCodePoint = KANJI.codePointAt(indexForThirdCodePoint);
    System.out.println(thirdCodePoint);

    // Convert codepoint back to string
    System.out.println(new String(Character.toChars(thirdCodePoint)));
  }
```

You could use the above techniques to obtain the start and end index of the codepoint that you require, and then use `substring(start, end)` to extract.

---

(edit) All of this could be simplified with a bit of judicious refactoring and utility functions.  Below is one possible example; I don't know the use case for your code is, so it's a bit hard to know what would be best for you.

```
public static final String KANJI = "";

public static int lengthCodepoints(String s)
{
  return s.codePointCount(0, s.length());
}

public static String substringCodepoint(String s, int startCodepoint, int numCodepoints)
{
  int startIndex = s.offsetByCodePoints(0, startCodepoint);
  int endIndex = s.offsetByCodePoints(startIndex, numCodepoints);
  return s.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int cpLength = lengthCodepoints(KANJI);
  for (int i = 0; i < cpLength; ++i)
  {
    System.out.println(substringCodepoint(KANJI, i, 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I can see how this would work.  Complicated though ...:)